# winform control reference in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have ASP.Net project and I have added a reference of System.Windows.Forms to the project. Then I have created a class by inheriting it from a Windows control.

```
public class winButton : Button
{
   public winButton()
   {
      this.Text = "Test";
   }
}
```

Then I built the solution. Then I was expecting that I will be seeing an extra control of name 'winButton' in the toolbox. But I was not able to. So is it not correct what I am hoping? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same solution I created a Winform project. My custom is visible in the toolbox now. So perhaps, controls inherited from Winform Control are not supported in Webform (ASP.Net) projects.

Answer (score -1):

> Then I was expecting that I will be seeing an extra control of name 'winButton' in the toolbox

Why were you expecting something like that? Controls do not just appear in the ToolBox automatically. You need to install the control manually by right clicking on the ToolBox -> Choose Items... and from the .NET Framework Components click on the Browse button and select the assembly that you compiled and which contains the custom button.

Comment: and why I can't expect it to behave like that. If I do it in the project, it has to appear in the toolbox automatically. I have done it 100s of times, in winforms by inheriting it from wiforms controls...but here, I am inheriting from a winform control in a webform project...thats the only difference. otherwise, Controls do appear automatically.

Comment: what you are saying happens when you create a new project of controls...in same or different solution